# how to get unique row names from table in array format?

Tags: php, arrays

i have a table called site, which records the name of some sites, now the table can have a hundred rows called site.com, and/or site.net, site.me....

now what i need is to get only the unique names, like even if there is 1000 row but only 5 types of sites names exist i need to get those site names.

so far, ive tried without success this

```
<?php 
 //mysql goes here
$query = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM SITES ");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
echo array_diff($row, NULL);
} ?>
```

nothing shows except argument error.

Comment: Use [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

Use the distinct key word.

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM SITES
```